# Automatically add comments out sign in the output of R Console or RStudio

Tags: r, console, rstudio

Currently we do the following:

```
> head(mtcars,n=3)
               mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710    22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
```

Is there a way to tweak the Console (R or RStudio) so that it output:

```
> head(mtcars,n=3)
#               mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Mazda RX4     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# Datsun 710    22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
```

Comment: Did you meant the `#` sign in output?

Comment: @akrun correct.

Answer (score 4):

Using [reprex](https://github.com/jennybc/reprex) package:

```
library(reprex)

reprex({head(mtcars, n = 3)}, comment = "#",  venue = "so")
# Rendered reprex is on the clipboard.
```

Result is saved to clipboard, when pasted it looks like this:

```
<!-- language-all: lang-r -->
  <br/>

  head(mtcars, n = 3)
#                mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Mazda RX4     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# Datsun 710    22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
```